# How and where to file USPTO Patent application?

Tags: filing, uspto, pro-se

1. What are the formats and ways to file US patent application and where to file?
2. List of Documents required to file Patent application?

Comment: this question is to list all requirements and help inventors

Answer (score 1):

1. You can file online:
   http://www.uspto.gov/patents/process/file/efs/index.jsp

Or you can send it in by mail to USPTO.
http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s501.html

2. Depends on what you want to file. Are you looking to file a provisional or a utility or a design patent? In any case, you can find it here:
   http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s601.html

MPEP is the Manual of Patent Examining Procedure and you can search it for most answers you have about patent procedures.